# what have I done wrong using pandas date range that every single february month has 28 days

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe

The output of this dataframe shows every february month as having 28 days

```
dates = pd.DataFrame({"start_date": pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), freq='MS')})
dates["start_date"] = dates["start_date"].apply(pd.datetools.normalize_date)
dates["end_date"] = dates["start_date"].shift(-1)
dates['end_date'] = dates['end_date'] - pd.offsets.Day(1)
dates["end_date"][1440]= datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 31).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
def prettyrow(start,end):
    result = end-start+ pd.offsets.Day(1)
    return result

data = []
for i in range(0,dates.shape[0]):
    days = prettyrow(dates["start_date"][i],dates["end_date"][i])
    data.append(int(str(days)[:2]))

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["days"])
timedata = pd.concat([dates, df], axis=1)
timedata
```

I've had to combine the two dataframes separately because I can't work out how to pass every row from specific dataframe columns to a function with more than one parameter.

As per comments below, the output of

> print(timedata[(timedata.start_date.dt.year%4 == 0) & (timedata.start_date.dt.month == 2)])

```
     start_date   end_date  days
1    1900-02-01 1900-02-28    28
49   1904-02-01 1904-02-29    29
97   1908-02-01 1908-02-29    29
145  1912-02-01 1912-02-29    29
193  1916-02-01 1916-02-29    29
241  1920-02-01 1920-02-29    29
289  1924-02-01 1924-02-29    29
337  1928-02-01 1928-02-29    29
385  1932-02-01 1932-02-29    29
433  1936-02-01 1936-02-29    29
481  1940-02-01 1940-02-29    29
529  1944-02-01 1944-02-29    29
577  1948-02-01 1948-02-29    29
625  1952-02-01 1952-02-29    29
673  1956-02-01 1956-02-29    29
721  1960-02-01 1960-02-29    29
769  1964-02-01 1964-02-29    29
817  1968-02-01 1968-02-29    29
865  1972-02-01 1972-02-29    29
913  1976-02-01 1976-02-29    29
961  1980-02-01 1980-02-29    29
1009 1984-02-01 1984-02-29    29
1057 1988-02-01 1988-02-29    29
1105 1992-02-01 1992-02-29    29
1153 1996-02-01 1996-02-29    29
1201 2000-02-01 2000-02-29    29
1249 2004-02-01 2004-02-29    29
1297 2008-02-01 2008-02-29    29
1345 2012-02-01 2012-02-29    29
1393 2016-02-01 2016-02-29    29
```

The output to the below comment is:

```
     start_date   end_date  days
1    1900-02-01 1900-02-28    28
49   1904-02-01 1904-02-29    29
97   1908-02-01 1908-02-29    29
145  1912-02-01 1912-02-29    29
193  1916-02-01 1916-02-29    29
241  1920-02-01 1920-02-29    29
289  1924-02-01 1924-02-29    29
337  1928-02-01 1928-02-29    29
385  1932-02-01 1932-02-29    29
433  1936-02-01 1936-02-29    29
481  1940-02-01 1940-02-29    29
529  1944-02-01 1944-02-29    29
577  1948-02-01 1948-02-29    29
625  1952-02-01 1952-02-29    29
673  1956-02-01 1956-02-29    29
721  1960-02-01 1960-02-29    29
769  1964-02-01 1964-02-29    29
817  1968-02-01 1968-02-29    29
865  1972-02-01 1972-02-29    29
913  1976-02-01 1976-02-29    29
961  1980-02-01 1980-02-29    29
1009 1984-02-01 1984-02-29    29
1057 1988-02-01 1988-02-29    29
1105 1992-02-01 1992-02-29    29
1153 1996-02-01 1996-02-29    29
1201 2000-02-01 2000-02-29    29
1249 2004-02-01 2004-02-29    29
1297 2008-02-01 2008-02-29    29
1345 2012-02-01 2012-02-29    29
1393 2016-02-01 2016-02-29    29
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce either, `timedata[1297:1298]` gives `1297 2008-02-01 2008-02-29    29`. Using Python 3.4-64 bit on Win10.

Comment: it works properly for me too (pandas 0.18.1, Python 3.5.1). What is the output of: `print(timedata[(timedata.start_date.dt.year%4 == 0) & (timedata.start_date.dt.month == 2)])` ?

Comment: Thanks everyone I'll post this output tonight

Comment: @MaxU see edit to original post - it contains the output to your question

Comment: @yoshiserry, so everything seems to be fine - you have your leap years...

Comment: @MaxU thanks I'll look over my code again